# UIPrerenderedIcon setting ignored in the AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have the UIPrerenderedIcon setting set to YES for my app bundle. It renders correctly on the iPhone home screen but in the AppStore and iTunes it is still adding the gloss.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/22931-how-get-no-gloss-icon-app-store.html) over on the iPhone Dev SDK forum, when the icon was uploaded in a `.png` or `.tiff` format, iTunes would automatically add gloss. However, when uploading it as a `.jpg`, the gloss wasn't added.

> I reuploaded the App Store Icon as 512 x 512 @ 72 dpi (Jpeg). Was originally 512 x 512 @ 300 dpi (tiff). Hope this helps others.

It seems like this is an odd problem – [another user](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/34021-shiny-app-store-icon.html) reports that it's a bug with iTunes Connect that results in it not honouring the `UIPrerenderedIcon` key.